# How to avoid matching numeric string that has # at the beginning?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation

I'm using below regular expression to match numbers that includes decimals, negative numbers inside quotes (").
What changes should I be doing so that it does not match "#1200"?

```
\"(-?\d*.?\d+)\"

"1200"     ---> matches as expected
"1200.67"  ---> matches as expected
"-1200"    ---> matches as expected
"-1200.67" ---> matches as expected
"#1200"    ---> I'm not expecting this to match. As you can see It has # at the beginning.
```

Comment: You need to escape the `.`.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's the `.` in your regular expression. You haven't escaped it so it's being interpreted as "match any character". It should work if you escape it like so:

```
\"(-?\d*\.?\d+)\"
```

Comment: Thanks! it works.